# wpf datagrid not showing data, but show rows

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I'm trying to make a simple WPF project and I have a problem:
the DataGrid is bound to an ObservableCollection, it does not show
the data, but it shows the correct amount of rows.Here's how it looks

[image: WPF DataGrid showing correct number of rows, but not showing data]

Here's XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="008.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:008"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow">

    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10">
            <Button Name="AddButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Margin="10">Add an element</Button>
            <Button Name="DeleteOldButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10">Delete old files</Button>
            <Button Name="ShowPop" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10">Show most popular element</Button>
        </StackPanel>

        <DataGrid Name="dgrid" CanUserResizeColumns="True"
                  CanUserAddRows="False"
                  IsReadOnly="True"
                  DataContext="files"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding}"

                  Width="Auto">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date created" Binding="{Binding Created}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Times Open" Binding="{Binding TimesOpen}"/>

            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

And here's the code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
    ObservableCollection<File> files;

    public MainWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        files = new ObservableCollection<File>();
        files.Add(new File("r", DateTime.Now));
        files.Add(new File("o", DateTime.Now));
        files.Add(new File("a", DateTime.Now));
        files.Add(new File("d", DateTime.Now));

    }

}
```

I've already tried setting the Window DataContext to files, it didn't work

**UPD:** Here's the File class:

```
class File
    {
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public DateTime Created { get; set; }
       public int TimesOpen { get; set; }

        public File(string s, DateTime d)
        {
            Created = d;
            Name = s;
            TimesOpen = 0;
        }
        public void Open()
        {
            TimesOpen++;
        }
    }
```

**UPD:** Implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged. Did not help. The File definition is below:

```
    class File: INotifyPropertyChanged 

    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private string name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set
            {
                if (!value.Equals(name,StringComparison.InvariantCulture)) {
                    OnPropertyChanged("Name");
                    name = value;
                }                     
            }

        }
        private DateTime created;
       public DateTime Created
        {
            get { return created; }
            set
            {
                if (!created.Equals(value))
                {
                    OnPropertyChanged("Created");
                    created = value;
                }
            }
        }
        private int times_open;
       public int TimesOpen
        {
            get { return times_open; }
            set
            {
                if (times_open != value)
                {
                    OnPropertyChanged("TimesOpen");
                    times_open = value;
                }
            }
        }

        public File(string s, DateTime d)
        {
            Created = d;
            Name = s;
            TimesOpen = 0;
        }

        void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }

        public void Open()
        {
            TimesOpen++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the definition for the File type?

Comment: Yes, of course, see the UPD

Comment: Have you tried making File implement INotifyPropertyChanged?  Put it on the Name, Created and TimeOpen properties.

Comment: Look at your exceptions--I'm seeing the following: `System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'TimesOpen' property not found on 'object' ''Char' (HashCode=7536755)'. BindingExpression:Path=TimesOpen; DataItem='Char' (HashCode=7536755); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things you are doing wrong
- You should set the datacontext for the window
- Your item source is bounded to files. But wait..
- Files needs to be a property in your datacontext, i.e. the mainwindow
- Additionally you should think about implementing INotifyPropertyChanged in your model

```
<DataGrid Name="dgrid" CanUserResizeColumns="True"
        CanUserAddRows="False"
        IsReadOnly="True"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Files}"
        Width="Auto">

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date created" Binding="{Binding Created}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Times Open" Binding="{Binding TimesOpen}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

and in you code behind use

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<File> Files {get; set;}


    public MainWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        Files = new ObservableCollection<File>();
        Files.Add(new File("r", DateTime.Now));
        Files.Add(new File("o", DateTime.Now));
        Files.Add(new File("a", DateTime.Now));
        Files.Add(new File("d", DateTime.Now));
        Files.Add(new File("d", DateTime.Now));
        Files.Add(new File("d", DateTime.Now));
    }
}
```

Comment: Implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged, tried setting the the DataContext to both this and files, made files a public property-nothing

Comment: @small-j No you should not set the datacontext to files. You set the datacontext as shown above in the constructor of mainwindow to this. And then you set the ItemsSource  to Files. You can just copy the code above. You don't even need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged to see the data in the grid. INotifyPropertyChanged will be useful when you want to notify the UI of the change in data later.

Comment: The class that implements your data for the grid has to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. `MainWindow.xaml.cs`:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        Files = new ObservableCollection<File>();
        Files.Add(new File("r", DateTime.Now));
        Files.Add(new File("o", DateTime.Now));
        Files.Add(new File("a", DateTime.Now));
        Files.Add(new File("d", DateTime.Now));
        DataContext = this;
    }
}

public ObservableCollection<File> Files { get; set; }
```

`MainWindow.xaml` (snippet):

```
<DataGrid Name="dgrid" CanUserResizeColumns="True"
                  CanUserAddRows="False"
                  IsReadOnly="True"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Files}"
                  Width="Auto">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date created" Binding="{Binding Created}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Times Open" Binding="{Binding TimesOpen}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```